# Computation regarding contour integrals and local logarithms

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I have been studying from an advanced book on complex analysis recently, one which emphasizes topological aspects. In the following theorem (showing existence of local logarithms on simply-connected domains for zero-free, holomorphic functions) I understood all but the final computation around the derivative of g(z), denoted by  the *red question mark*.
[image: Theorem 1.21]
I'm not sure why this is specifically causing me trouble, but I'd appreciate it if someone were to write out the intermediate steps there. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$g(z+h) = \int_{z_0}^{z+h} \frac{f'(\zeta)}{f(\zeta)} \; d\zeta$$ where it doesn't matter what path we take within $\Omega$.  So let's take a path that first goes from $z_0$ to $z$ and then in a straight line to $z+h$.  Now subtract $g(z)$ which is the integral from $z_0$ to $z$, and we're left with the integral from $z$ to $z+h$, i.e.

$$ g(z+h) - g(z) = \int_{z}^{z+h} \frac{f'(\zeta)}{f(\zeta)}\; d\zeta$$

Parametrize the path from $z$ to $z+h$ as $\zeta = z + th$, $0 \le t \le 1$, and
this is

$$ g(z+h) - g(z) = \int_0^1 \frac{f'(z+th)}{f(z+th)}\; h\; dt $$

so
$$ \frac{g(z+h) - g(z)}{h} = \int_0^1 \frac{f'(z+th)}{f(z+th)}\; dt $$

Finally, take the limit as $h \to 0$: $f(z+th) \to f(z) \ne 0$ and $f'(z+th) \to f'(z)$ (both uniformly in $t \in [0,1]$), so $f'(z+th)/f(z+th) \to f'(z)/f(z)$ uniformly in $t \in [0,1]$, and
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{f'(z+th)}{f(z+th)}\; dt \to \int_0^1 \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\; dt = \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$$